# Keep all columns after groupby with .agg (many columns) more effective

Tags: python, pandas

I have found a few topics connected with this problem, "how to keep all columns after groupby" but my problem is, that i know how, but I dont know how to do it more effective.

example:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,2,3], 'B':[2,2,4,3],'d':[2,np.nan,1,4],'e':['this is','my life','not use 1','not use 2'],'f':[1,2,3,4]
                 })

print(df)
   A  B    d          e  f
0  1  2  2.0    this is  1
1  1  2  NaN    my life  2
2  2  4  1.0  not use 1  3
3  3  3  4.0  not use 2  4
```

I need to join strings from column `e` if columns `A and B` are equal.
to do that i am using this code:

```
df=df.groupby(['A','B'],as_index=False).agg({'e':' '.join,'d':'first','f':'first'})
print(df)
   A  B    d  f                e
0  1  2  2.0  1  this is my life
1  2  4  1.0  3        not use 1
2  3  3  4.0  4        not use 2
```

and this is correct output for me.
But as you can see, to keep column `f and d` I need to put them inside of this `agg dict` one by one.
In my real data i have 20 columns, and I dont want to manually put names of all those columns in my code.

**Is there any better solution to keep all columns after groupby, 
or any way to improve my solution, than i am using right now?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create dictionary dynamic with [`Index.difference`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html) for all columns values exclude list and [`dict.fromkeys`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict%20fromkeys#dict.fromkeys) method for dictionary and then add `e` to dictionary:

```
d = dict.fromkeys(df.columns.difference(['A','B','e']), 'first')
print(d)
{'d': 'first', 'f': 'first'}

d['e'] = ' '.join
print(d)
{'d': 'first', 'f': 'first', 'e': <built-in method join of str object at 0x00000000025E1880>}
```

Or you can create both dictionaries separately and `merge` them together:

```
d1 = dict.fromkeys(df.columns.difference(['A','B','e']), 'first')
d2 = {'e': ' '.join}

d = {**d1, **d2}
```

---

```
df=df.groupby(['A','B'],as_index=False).agg(d)
print(df)
   A  B    d  f                e
0  1  2  2.0  1  this is my life
1  2  4  1.0  3        not use 1
2  3  3  4.0  4        not use 2
```

Last if order is important same like original add [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df=df.groupby(['A','B'],as_index=False).agg(d).reindex(df.columns, axis=1)
print (df)
   A  B    d                e  f
0  1  2  2.0  this is my life  1
1  2  4  1.0        not use 1  3
2  3  3  4.0        not use 2  4
```

Comment: thanks, can you give me short explanation of first line, what is going on there ?